# AWS API Gateway SDK "is not a function" error

Tags: aws-sdk

Implemented AWS API Gateway SDK for javascript. Calling this AWS API Gateway method throws an error:

```
var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient(); 
apigClient.ultrafindGet(params, body, additionalParams)
.then(function(result){
```

Here's the error in the javascript console:

[image: not a function error]

Calling a different resource and method ('memberlookupGet') from the **same** AWS API Gateway does **not** throw an error:

```
var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient(); 
apigClient.memberlookupGet(params, body, additionalParams)
.then(function(result){
```

- Both method endpoints return correct json when called directly from the browser
- Both methods are included in apigClient.js
- **CORS** enabled for both methods
- Both methods have one querystring request param called 'membername'

Answer (score 1):

Old version of apigClient.js was cached in browser.
Cleared cache.
Fixed.